# How to echo these foreach arrays properly?

Tags: php

Working on a project, am pretty new to PHP and don't know how to do this in a better way.

```php
    $item_thumbnails = array(
        "https://brkcdn.com/v2/images/shop/thumbnails/f7dd8e95-551f-5e1f-92f1-2ea6c29e61ca.png",
        "https://brkcdn.com/v2/images/shop/thumbnails/9fd1ea9d-cfd0-525a-963f-0c3438c5dc34.png"
    );

    $item_names = array(
        "brick-luke's Fedora",
        "Golden Bok"
    );

    $item_urls = array(
        "https://www.brick-hill.com/shop/20/",
        "https://www.brick-hill.com/shop/10267/"
    );

    $item_values = array(
        "30.000",
        "100.000"
    );

    $item_demands = array(
        "High",
        "Low"
    );


    foreach ($item_urls as $key => $item_url) {
    foreach ($item_thumbnails as $key => $item_thumbnail) {}
    foreach ($item_names as $key => $item_name) {}
    foreach ($item_values as $key => $item_value) {}
    foreach ($item_demands as $key => $item_demand) {}
        echo ('
        <div class="card">
            <a class="image" href="'.$item_url.'">
                <img src="'.$item_thumbnail.'" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src="'.$storageUrl.'/error.png"">
            </a>
            <div class="content">
            <a class="header">'.$item_name.'</a>
                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                Value: <div class="ui right floated red horizontal label">'.$item_value.'</div>
                <div class="ui divider"></div>
                Demand: <div class="ui right floated green horizontal label">'.$item_demand.'</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ');
    }
```

It only shows the latest item in the array on all tabs (if there are more).

How to fix this? Help is appreciated.

Comment: You do know `{}` does nothing, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$item_thumbnails = array(
    "https://brkcdn.com/v2/images/shop/thumbnails/f7dd8e95-551f-5e1f-92f1-2ea6c29e61ca.png",
    "https://brkcdn.com/v2/images/shop/thumbnails/9fd1ea9d-cfd0-525a-963f-0c3438c5dc34.png"
);

$item_names = array(
    "brick-luke's Fedora",
    "Golden Bok"
);

$item_urls = array(
    "https://www.brick-hill.com/shop/20/",
    "https://www.brick-hill.com/shop/10267/"
);

$item_values = array(
    "30.000",
    "100.000"
);

$item_demands = array(
    "High",
    "Low"
);

// iterate over one array and get values from 
// other arrays under the same key `$key`
foreach ($item_urls as $key => $item_url) {
    echo ('
    <div class="card">
        <a class="image" href="'.$item_url.'">
            <img src="' . $item_thumbnails[$key] . '" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src="'.$storageUrl.'/error.png"">
        </a>
        <div class="content">
        <a class="header">' . $item_names[$key] . '</a>
            <div class="ui divider"></div>
            Value: <div class="ui right floated red horizontal label">' . $item_values[$key] . '</div>
            <div class="ui divider"></div>
            Demand: <div class="ui right floated green horizontal label">' . $item_demands[$key] . '</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should improve your array structure.

```
$items = array(
  [
    "thumbnail" => "https://brkcdn.com/v2/images/shop/thumbnails/f7dd8e95-551f-5e1f-92f1-2ea6c29e61ca.png"
    "name" => "brick-luke's Fedora",
    "url" => "https://www.brick-hill.com/shop/20/",
    "value" => "30.000",
    "demand" => "High"
  ],
  [
    "thumbnail" => "https://brkcdn.com/v2/images/shop/thumbnails/9fd1ea9d-cfd0-525a-963f-0c3438c5dc34.png",
    "name" => "Golden Bok",
    "url" => "https://www.brick-hill.com/shop/10267/",
    "value" => "100.000",
    "demand" => "Low"
  ]
);
```

After that you can foreach ***$items*** variable and take data from it. See below:

```
<?php
foreach ($items as $item) {
?>

<div class="card">
  <a class="image" href="<?php echo $item['url']; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $item['thumbnail']; ?>" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=<?php echo $storageUrl; ?>/error.png">
  </a>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="header"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></a>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    Value: <div class="ui right floated red horizontal label"><?php echo $item['value']; ?></div>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    Demand: <div class="ui right floated green horizontal label"><?php echo $item['demand']; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Enjoy!